# DirectX D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain returning E_INVALIDARG

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11

I have the following call, and no matter what I try, `hresult` is always E_INVALIDARG:

```
LogMessage(L"Creating swap chain. Emulation: " + std::to_wstring(useSoftwareEmulation) + L", Debugging: " + std::to_wstring(enableRenderDebugging));
HRESULT hresult = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(
    (useSoftwareEmulation ? NULL : currentAdapter), 
    (useSoftwareEmulation ? D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP : D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_UNKNOWN), 
    NULL, 
    (enableRenderDebugging ? D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG | D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUGGABLE : 0),
    NULL,
    0,
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION,
    &swapChainDescriptor, 
    &swapChain,
    &graphicsCardInterface, 
    &runningFeatureLevel, 
    &graphicsCardContext
    );
```

According to the log line above, both `useSoftwareEmulation` and `enableRenderDebugging` are *false*.

The types of all the other variables are as such:

**`currentAdapter`** is a `IDXGIAdapter*`

**`swapChainDescriptor`** is a `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC`

**`swapChain`** is a `IDXGISwapChain*`

**`graphicsCardInterface`** is a `ID3D11Device*`

**`runningFeatureLevel`** is a `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL`

**`graphicsCardContext`** is a `ID3D11DeviceContext*`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

False alarm: I had an error in my swapChainDescriptor (namely, my MSAA count and quality values were swapped).

Hope this might help anyone else in the future.

Comment: Pass D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG to D3D11CreateDevice flags to catch errors like this.

Comment: @MooseBoys I see nothing on the output window even when I pass those parameters. Strange. Maybe they only show information for actual graphics calls once you've set up the device + swapchain?

Comment: Yes that makes sense since you're using the CreateDeviceAndSwapChain call and the call is failing.  I thin if you use D3D11CreateDevice followed by IDXGIFactory::CreateSwapChain, you should see the debug info.