# Using D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain?

Tags: c++, directx

I am currently writing a DirectX 11 game engine in C++ based off a tutorial, but I ran into a problem. Here is where the error is:

```
result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL,    
0, &featureLevel, 1, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, 
&m_device, NULL, &m_deviceContext);
```

result = `HRESULT`, featureLevel = `D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL`, swapChainDesc = `DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC`, m_swapChain = `IDXGISwapChain*`, m_device = `ID3D11Device*`, and finally m_deviceContext = `ID3D11DeviceContext*`.

When I run this, I get a value of something like -5027..., so that doesn't work. I also looked at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19348787/directx-d3d11createdeviceandswapchain-returning-e-invalidarg) article to try what they had, but it ended up crashing my computer(I had modified the code a little to my varibles, ending up with `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, NULL, 0, NULL, 0, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, &m_device, &featureLevel, &m_deviceContext);`).

Does anyone know how to solve this issue? I can upload my whole program to pastebin, just ask. Also, [here is the link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a1y7yYPEx7s) to the tutorial if you want to look over it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your hardware does not fully support DirectX11 feature level,
so try to use this

```
result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP, NULL,    
0, &featureLevel, 1, D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &m_swapChain, 
&m_device, NULL, &m_deviceContext);
```

`D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE` Flag means that the **D3Device** will be created on hardware mode if the graphics's card support **DX11** feature level, the Program will use full capability of this graphics's card, otherwise the creation will fails.
`D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP` Flag, made **D3Device** use the software mode this make the Program able to run on graphics's card tha t don't support **DX11** but not on the full speed.

for more information about driver types please see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476328(v=vs.85).aspx

because you are not sure about the hardware that your app running on so the good practice is to do:

```
// Driver types
D3D_DRIVER_TYPE driverTypes[] =
{
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_WARP,
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_REFERENCE,
};

// feature levels
D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL featureLevels[] =
{
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_0,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1,
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_0,
};

int numDriverTypes = ARRAYSIZE( driverTypes );
int numFeatureLevels = ARRAYSIZE( featureLevels );
```

your app will loop and test every driver type with every feature level in those arrays, if succeeds then **DXDevice** will created with the correct feature level and driver mode

```
 for( int driverTypeIndex = 0; driverTypeIndex < numDriverTypes; driverTypeIndex ++ )
    {
       result = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain( NULL, driverTypes[driverTypeIndex], NULL, createDeviceFlags, featureLevels, numFeatureLevels,
                                            D3D11_SDK_VERSION, &swapChainDesc, &swapChain, &m_device, &featureLevel, &m_deviceContext);
        if( SUCCEEDED( result ) )
            break;
    }
```